# How to read a property injected from file.properties in WSO2 - micro integrator?

Tags: wso2

Is there a way to read the properties from file in wso2 using **property mediator**?

I'm injecting an address uri from the file.properties, and passing the file path as -Dproperties.file.path argument to the startup script, it is able to resolve the varibale only within the address endpoint's uri attribute using the syntax $FILE:variableName as below:

```
                <call>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address uri="$FILE:uploadPath">
                            <suspendOnFailure>
                                <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                            </suspendOnFailure>
                            <markForSuspension>
                                <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                            </markForSuspension>
                        </address>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
```

But I also have the need to use the same property, do a minor transformation and pass it to a class mediator,

I've tried the below approaches and none of them are working.

```
<log level="custom">
  <property expression="$FILE:uploadPath" name="file-path-1"/>
  <property expression="$ctx:uploadPath" name="file-path-2"/>
  <property expression="$axis2:uploadPath" name="file-path-3"/>
  <property expression="$trp:uploadPath" name="file-path-4"/>
  <property expression="$axis2:POST_TO_URI" name="POST_TO_URI"/>
</log>
```

Below are the versions of OS and tools that I'm using.
OS: Mac os catalina,
WSO2: micro-integrator 1.2.0, Integration sutdio - 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, i was struggling with similar issue, to try using $FILE: in dockered microintegrator . After checking sourcecode i realized that there is no implemented reading in property mediator, and that works only in endpoints... I belive that is because of security reason?

But, there is some workaround, which I'm not a big fan. You could use Property and ScriptMediator:

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="propPath" expression="get-property('system','properties.file.path')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<script language="js"><![CDATA[
   var path = java.nio.file.Paths.get(mc.getProperty('propPath'));
   var fromFile = java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(path, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

   mc.setProperty('line1',fromFile.get(0).toString());
   mc.setProperty('line2',fromFile.get(1).toString());
]]></script>
```

Of course you got full line, but if you tweak this ScriptMediator, you can have what you want in separate properties.

Answer (score 0):

The below sample describes a configuration approach for WSO2 MI where properties are read from a file and extract the value using a property mediator.

```
<property expression="get-property('file', 'stockQuoteEP')" name="uri.var.x"/>
```

Using a property mediator to read the property named 'stockQuoteEP' from a file and assign it to the variable 'uri.var.x'.

Store Values in a Properties File:
The values are expected to be stored in a properties file, by default there is a file named file.properties in MI_HOME/conf or a custom file name specified during server startup.

**Custom File Name and Path:**
If you are using a different file name or path, you can specify it during the server startup script using the -Dproperties.file.path=/path/to/your/file.properties option.

**Automatic Loading:**
The system is expected to automatically load the properties from the specified file during its startup process.

**Sample Proxy service:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Respond"
       transports="http https"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom" category="INFO">
            <property name="Request in" value="********** message in ********* "/>
         </log>
         <property expression="get-property('file', 'stockQuoteEP')" name="Param"/>
         <log level="custom" category="INFO">
            <property name="Param" expression="$ctx:Param"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```