# How can we inject properties into wso2 Micro Integrator and Enterprise Integrator using file.properties?

Tags: properties, wso2, configuration-files, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I want to use the .car file on another server without using integration studio. So I want to be able to change the hostname and port dynamically using a configuration file. My endpoint URL has variables in it {uri.var.x} that's why I can't use $FILE:x to get the complete URL from file.properties.

I have already tried [How to read a property injected from file.properties in WSO2 - micro integrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66218927/how-to-read-a-property-injected-from-file-properties-in-wso2-micro-integrator) but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply read the Property from the file and assign it to the variable you desire. Then use it in your Endpoint configurations.

```xml
<property expression="get-property('file', 'x')" name="uri.var.x"/>
```

You can store the values in a properties file called `file.properties` in the `MI_HOME/conf` folder and it will be loaded automatically. If you are using a different fileName you can pass it to the server startup script like `-Dproperties.file.path=/home/dev/dev.properties`. Then you can read them through a Property Mediator.

Further, if you want to construct the full URL from multiple properties you can use Xpath functions.

```xml
<property expression="concat('https://', get-property('file', 'host'), ':', get-property('file', 'port'))" name="uri.var.x" scope="default" type="STRING" />
```

---

If the properties are not picked from the default file, pass the file path like below.

```
sh micro-integrator.sh -Dproperties.file.path=./conf/file.properties
```

---

**Update on WSO2 EI**

It seems file scope is not supported in EI. But instead, you can read variables from Environment variables with `get-property('env', 'NAME_OF_VARIABLE')`

```xml
<property expression="concat('https://', get-property('env', 'host'), ':', get-property('env', 'port'))" name="uri.var.x" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

If you want to read them from a properties file, you can do something like the below. Assuming you have a properties file like below.

```
stockQuoteEP=http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService
ycr=test1234
host=localycr
port=6676
```

Add the following script to `integrator.sh` to export the properties as environment variables. You can improve the script as you require.

```bash
while read line; do
   echo "Exporting $line" 
   export $line
done < /home/wso2/wso2ei-6.6.0/conf/file.properties
```

[image]

Then in your integration read them as below.

```xml
<property expression="concat('https://', get-property('env', 'host'), ':', get-property('env', 'port'))" name="uri.var.x" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

---

**Update 2 on File Scope in Property mediator**

As Sanoj mentioned, `file` scope in the property mediator is only available from MI 4.0 onward vanilla packs. If you have a WSO2 subscription you can get it as an update for both MI and EI.

Comment: I'm using the file.properties but i'm still getting a null value to the property .. is 'file' supposed to be 'file.properties'? or the path of the file ?

Comment: @JosephElia `file` just indicates it should be read from a file or in other words the scope of the variable. Try starting MI like `sh micro-integrator.sh -Dproperties.file.path=./conf/file.properties`

Comment: I'm still getting a null value . Do you think using wso2 EI instead of MI is a problem?

Comment: @JosephElia what the EI version you are using?

Comment: it is the latest EI version 6.6.0

Comment: @JosephElia It seems EI doesn't support `file` scope. I have added a solution. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: @JosephElia, the `file` scope is supported from EI 6.6.0.104 onwards. But you will need a WSO2 subscription to update the product. https://wso2.com/subscription/

Comment: @ycr , is  the file scope supported in MI ? if yes which version are you using ?

Comment: MI 4.0.0 upwards has the file scope support in the vanilla packs

Comment: Thank you guys i was able to solve the problem using MI 4.1.0 and the solution provided by @ycr , using the file scope .

Comment: @sanoJ Thanks for confirming. I updated the answer with the information.